# Creating a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create one component (one HTML-circle) in React, but I get 'unknown error':

```js
ReactDom.render(
  <main>
    <h1>Below is my component</h1>
      <Html_component />
  </main>, document.getElementById('root') );
  
  function Html_component(){
  return(
    <main>
      <div style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: black; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can you please share your error message here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReactDOM.render` expects as first argument an instantiated component, you are just passing `jsx`.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>Below is my component</h1>
            <Html_component />
        </main>
    )
}

function Html_component() {
    return (
        <main>
            <div style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: black; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
        </main>
    )
}

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Remeber, a functional `component` is a function which returns `jsx`

Answer (score 1):

See the following examples, save each code as html files(say example1.html and example2.html) and open in a browser you can see the result

- Simple example without using jsx

> ```
> <head>
>   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
>   <title>Hello World</title>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>   <div id="root"></div>
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>
>     ReactDOM.render(
>       React.createElement(
>         "main",
>         null,
>         React.createElement("h1", null, "Below is my component"),
>         React.createElement(Html_component, null)
>       ),
>       document.getElementById("root")
>     );
>
>     function Html_component() {
>       return React.createElement(
>         "main",
>         null,
>         React.createElement("div", {
>           style: {
>             borderRadius: "50%",
>             backgroundColor: "black",
>             width: "10px",
>             height: "10px"
>           }
>         })
>       );
>     }
>
>   </script>
>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

- Example using jsx

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>
> <head>
>   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
>   <title>Hello World</title>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
>
>   <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>   <div id="root"></div>
>   <script type="text/babel">
>
>     ReactDOM.render(
>       <main>
>         <h1>Below is my component</h1>
>         <Html_component />
>       </main>,
>       document.getElementById("root")
>     );
>
>     function Html_component() {
>       return (
>         <main>
>           <div
>             style={{
>               borderRadius: "50%",
>               backgroundColor: "black",
>               width: "10px",
>               height: "10px"
>             }}
>           ></div>
>         </main>
>       );
>     }
>
>
>   </script>
>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

you can see more details about jsx here https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 0):

spell mistake and style property change

try this

```
function Html_component() {
return (
    <main>
        <div style={{ 'border-radius': "50%", 'background-color': 'black', width: '10px', height: '10px' }}></div>
    </main>
)}   

ReactDOM.render(
<main>
    <h1>Below is my component</h1>
    <Html_component />
</main>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This won't work. You're still passing a `jsx` statement to `ReactDOM.render`

Answer (score 0):

This is better concept to use always class model with defined state params , props and maybe callback ...

Include interface's also...

```js
interface propsInterface {
  title: string
};

interface stateInterface {
  visibility: boolean
};

class Below extends React.Component <propsInterface, stateInterface > {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { visible: true};
 }
  
 render() {
  if (this.state.visible === true) {
    return (
     <main>
      <div>{this.props.title}</div>
     </main>
   );
  } else {
    return (<div></div>);
  }
  }  
 };
  
  
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Below title="Below component." />,
   document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```